# Variable not set to if statement

Tags: bash, shell

```sh
order_file="order"

read_order_file() {
    while read line; do
        #get file and file path from order file
        b=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }')
        a="x86_64${b}"
        echo $a
    
        if [ -f $a ]
        then
            echo 'ok'
        else
            echo 'No'
        fi    
    done < $order_file
}

read_order_file
```

In above code I am reading an order file using a while loop and getting a file name with a path to variable `a`. I need to check whether the file exists or not. I use `if [-f $a ]`, but the condition always fails. when I `echo $a` it shows correct file and path. Why is that?

Comment: Does the variable `$a` refer to a file or a directory? The `-f` test will return false if it's a directory - might that be the problem?

Comment: $a is file name and path ex: /var/www/index.html

Comment: So there are files prefixed with "x86_64" in the same directory as the script that is being executed?

Comment: Script running ok. Problem is it is always show 'No' as output

Comment: when I set a="x86_64/Packages/yelp-xsl-3.28.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm" it gives 'Ok'.

Comment: Can we see an extract from the order file?

Comment: @ThilinaSameera : While not a problem with this particular file, you would have to write either `[ -f "$a" ]` or `[[ -f $a ]]`. Other things I would try is to do a `[[ -e $a ]]` instead (maybe it's not a plain file), and for debugging, I would do in any case a `stat "$a"`, or, if you prefer, a `ls -ld "$a"` before querying the file.

Comment: here is order file

```14750   /Packages/qt5-qtsvg-devel-5.9.7-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
14751   /Packages/mesa-libGLw-devel-8.0.0-5.el7.i686.rpm
14752   /Packages/mesa-libGLU-devel-9.0.0-4.el7.i686.rpm
14753   /Packages/libepoxy-devel-1.5.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
14754   /Packages/mesa-libGLw-devel-8.0.0-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
14755   /Packages/mesa-libEGL-devel-18.3.4-10.el7.i686.rpm
14756   /Packages/mariadb-devel-5.5.68-1.el7.i686.rpm
14757   /Packages/libvirt-devel-4.5.0-36.el7.2.x86_64.rpm
14758   /Packages/liboauth-devel-0.9.7-4.el7.i686.rpm```

Comment: 2 debugging recommendations: Have the script run `pwd` to make sure its working directory is what you expect (& where the `x86_64/Packages/...` files are). Also, put `set -x` before the problem section, to make it print out what's happening as the script runs; look for anything weird/unexpected in what gets printed.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'` is an anti-pattern.  Let `read` split the line for you: `while read size path _; do ...`

Answer (score 1):

When your order file has lines ending with `\r\n` (Windows line endings), the `$a` will have a `\r` in its name.
You can change your `order_file` before running the script or chage your script:

Change the line with `done` into

```
done < <( tr -d '\r' < $order_file)
```

or quote the variable (filename can have a space):

```
done < <( tr -d '\r' < "$order_file")
```